# Error in web.config in vs 2015

Tags: asp.net

Hello i got this error. Can anyone help me to resolve this.

when i am going to comment this seection it will open through iis ,
but as it is not working.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
Line 31:       <assemblies>
Line 32:         <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
Line 33:         <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
Line 34:         <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataDefModel, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: What error exactly do you have? And what are you asking?

Comment: i got this error when i am going to build using iis. It is crystal report i think. Can u give me exact soln?